# ag-grid cell edit allow only numbers

Tags: angular, ag-grid

How to make simple input type="number" in ag-grid cell?
something like this:

```
cellRenderer: params => {
        if (isNaN(Number(params.value))
        {
            return params.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, '');
        } else {
            return params.value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately there is no one simple way to do this.
In my case I created separate component like on the official page [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editor/#angular-cell-editing).
I hope in close future they change this because now it is very unclear and complicated.
Thanks everyone for help!

Comment: Yeah it's bonkers

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is like 'Shotgun'. It will take care of invalid input not only at editing but even if there is some wrong value is supplied at rendering(getting data from source).

You have to define a custom component to take care of user input.

```
var columnDefs = [
    {
        field: "value",
        editable: true,
        cellEditorSelector: function (params) {
            if (params.data.type === 'age') { // here you can check using your logic if it needs numericCelleditor or not
                return {
                    component: 'numericCellEditor'
                };
            }
             return null;
        ...
        ...
```

Custom Editor Component [Ref Documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#example-dynamic-editor-component)

```
// function to act as a class
function NumericCellEditor() {
}

// gets called once before the renderer is used
NumericCellEditor.prototype.init = function (params) {
    // create the cell
    this.eInput = document.createElement('input');

    if (isCharNumeric(params.charPress)) {
        this.eInput.value = params.charPress;
    } else {
        if (params.value !== undefined && params.value !== null) {
            this.eInput.value = params.value;
        }
    }

    var that = this;
    this.eInput.addEventListener('keypress', function (event) {
        if (!isKeyPressedNumeric(event)) {
            that.eInput.focus();
            if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
        } else if (that.isKeyPressedNavigation(event)){
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
    });

    // only start edit if key pressed is a number, not a letter
    var charPressIsNotANumber = params.charPress && ('1234567890'.indexOf(params.charPress) < 0);
    this.cancelBeforeStart = charPressIsNotANumber;
};

NumericCellEditor.prototype.isKeyPressedNavigation = function (event){
    return event.keyCode===39
        || event.keyCode===37;
};


// gets called once when grid ready to insert the element
NumericCellEditor.prototype.getGui = function () {
    return this.eInput;
};

// focus and select can be done after the gui is attached
NumericCellEditor.prototype.afterGuiAttached = function () {
    this.eInput.focus();
};

// returns the new value after editing
NumericCellEditor.prototype.isCancelBeforeStart = function () {
    return this.cancelBeforeStart;
};

// example - will reject the number if it contains the value 007
// - not very practical, but demonstrates the method.
NumericCellEditor.prototype.isCancelAfterEnd = function () {
    var value = this.getValue();
    return value.indexOf('007') >= 0;
};

// returns the new value after editing
NumericCellEditor.prototype.getValue = function () {
    return this.eInput.value;
};

// any cleanup we need to be done here
NumericCellEditor.prototype.destroy = function () {
    // but this example is simple, no cleanup, we could  even leave this method out as it's optional
};

// if true, then this editor will appear in a popup 
NumericCellEditor.prototype.isPopup = function () {
    // and we could leave this method out also, false is the default
    return false;
};
```

Comment: You may want to use [framework component](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editor/#angular-cell-editing) since OP is using angular

Answer (score 2):

The most Easy way till now in ag-grid

//to make sure user entered number only

```
valueSetter: (params: ValueSetterParams) => {  //to make sure user entered number only
      var newValInt = parseInt(params.newValue);
      var valueChanged = params.data.age!== newValInt;
      if (valueChanged) {
        params.data.age= newValInt ? newValInt : params.oldValue;

      }

      return valueChanged;
    },
```

full code sample:

```
{
    headerName: "Age",
    field: "age",
    width: 100,
    editable: true,
    sortable: true,
    filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
    floatingFilter: true,
    floatingFilterComponentParams: { suppressFilterButton: true },
    valueSetter: (params: ValueSetterParams) => {  //to make sure user entered number only
      var newValInt = parseInt(params.newValue);
      var valueChanged = params.data.age !== newValInt;
      if (valueChanged) {
        params.data.age = newValInt ? newValInt : params.oldValue;

      }

      return valueChanged;
    },
  },
```

**IMPORTANT**
it worked for me with angular Typescript .

Answer (score 0):

its working for my angular app:
note: if user input value "not a number" - will not be saved this value (will be saved old value)

```
public columnDefs: ColDef[] = [

{ headerName: 'number', 
field: 'number', 
editable: true, 
singleClickEdit: true,
valueParser: this.numberParser
}
]


numberParser(params: ValueParserParams): number | string {
 return Number.isNaN(Number(params.newValue)) ? params.oldValue : Number(params.newValue);
}
```